# if statement and printing in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean

i dont know why this code not printing 'got it'
when i run it it just shows me the prints the else statement , even if the answer is correct.

```
import random as rand
print('Welcome to the guessing game!')
print('type a number between 1 to 9')
running = True
while running:
    value = rand.randint(1, 9)
    user_guess = input()

    if user_guess == value:
        print('got it')
    else:
        print('not at all')
```

even ive tried with printing the value to make sure my answer is correct.

Comment: Try `print(type(user_guess), type(value))`

Comment: didn't understood

Comment: `str != int`, it never will... you will need to convert `user_guess` to `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: thanks bro got it !

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after

```
user_guess = input()
```

`user_guess` will be a `str` and `value` is an `int`.
At statement `if user_guess == value:` you trying to compare `str` with `int`.
Try

```
user_guess = int(input())
```